# Access and download files with dynamic cookie using cURL

Tags: linux, perl, curl

I have a perl script in bash which uses cURL to download the files over HTTPS using username/password and cookie. However, I found that the cookie is dynamic thus hardcoding it would not work. Thus, I would like to inquire if you have a better solution for this problem.

Below is my current code.

```
    # This just pulls the webpage. Will need to parse out the HTML Table chunk into a CSV
        print "Downloading $target_file.html\n";
                if  ($filespec eq "file1")  {
my $curl_code = `curl "https://sample.com/wells/CompositionReportResult.asp?ReportId=123"   -H 'Cookie: SMDEVICE=eyJhbGciOiJBMTI4S1ciLCJlbmMiOiJBMTI4Q0JDLUhTMjU2In0.0lMlSBb0mzYbuV6M0P9Qst0JijUl2YvuVxaBtAsVEfcUkKLRsO2p1w.PC
Y7zSD0HHuUCZZSsEbnFg.Z5QUEHlGNDQDoL8UsIKnakAxalwcGU7CX5rUerKKbrem25tc8GyIcmxPasp4KzFF9caR20lH7_lc6M1QlYssBEYEcI4DM50P-t8Mtr-PhDA.-Vdgrpt4t96Lk_N1hPCMYg; SMUSRMSG=; Navajo=+eGoE8a0fQmcgzcWwCp5hHDE/d2qhD+3PWhAGpDtbjdcarcbVJ04ReK6NKYsEQp
6Rnew1GOvnH0-; SMSESSION=LtzURcRBZWhHbcJTfzHBMmf+TKgP6SLlM5r1l6HXDUB4xsOPw+G0lJleBwYDcLPotLXzu5+arzlceezQP2oc/cCmsi9K86aIzn9DkNlJhZUUPDX6SzvSxRxZDJDvsyAsDFv+Tn+0hixJ4f7fHk0ATYFMUjyy7nM3DnW9kxHUuwfrAxHGnj5zvBRKzMTV0jM6Eotgc8jUJS6ehEwZX
GEIVC7QIuk3dtJqaSEXzkI6m4Bxi7VUq522ajQ618rsC3ICS3gy/y/+RnpfAHEFkJHwWpCP4kz1byYdSjKmDaq8cxnIJWXENCxUj2OuKEkJw8izZfum47+5FfI2gAPnv1aq5W+902r/AwSOSJfT8YBCCWHARbf1hab2Jwk9XfFxmWUDNsVa6oxTLc3/LQ1fEO7rd9lVqlyPUD9q+U53I5IZ6UybyrNzRNrGY11tftc
Glo0FDlVpmpboebeJXnIk+JPDB9azB8/QC1cKoGU+3VvmikUsvMx2/I6ZNRbagJKMUo4zSEsOcaLMgV8WrLVDifg7brUvASDQSXsKgWisIoQfVhiVGWsKJl0ovQ9Eeih1iTQpt05FpDXiigsb0cFz/vcRCt6chszLT99kKoO29Ck0abro4Tir4ZTOXSAAyu108C0+f1sWCjvM/FX4Myer/pgSDQfXzy5w/7mdVLSlQd
SNBIAzjDZdrAk2vxsLeYR6UjJLJocPeC/YOBwSC438IVw0LSay1oBsLv0OlQukMvxKuPnvROPHvIecXNN3PrYenR4ctYtw+rLZCAVh0RGuKzkgjC1DMxk9g1mPmFGPmmUI9nRQ+NI2BD1CQt2Np1zI29Ow7bOqc6OhobsV2C5wpmKZwEqRjeNqaNJGuwYYJwId6vmKgq5wq0J60CcOXOCjN/EX5YwVbLERPAN/3F1h
n3h/c52odG2CTkGwq1B4ns/6Uc06XW3SSB+olODwgLmRqUQgrlajyPdYiub6JJMpA+hf4iGSiz3LV7s4efSPPIUCM/5DKy9kcoQWmjsbPVoBCpS4Aywnc0xAhRpbK6KeO6dzndVvoZC8D9aQj4MBMoTTJBZGrAIr2WkE71msMIvg2BmFRegsTqODLHNJqxZfBeNxVHcO+bk8RUbje3+QmCmY6Tc6Nl9jbfH3I5k0zB
g9SQ/x6HWNOKv7NuTZHQ9uiC6DslxLXX87eZV0L+4SF2QMtkwl82pHXGtcMkk2F9desk0dHB406LCRCki3+DYQTuQMfDH/HYIuQzvpuCrzIRpHZvIpoA7sR+tgEkUFVhibK/gVM'  --compressed >  "$httpsconf->{localdir}/$target_file.html"`;
                } elsif ($filespec eq "file2") {
my $curl_code = `curl "https://sample.com/wells/MainReportResult.asp?ReportId=456"   -H 'Cookie: SMDEVICE=eyJhbGciOiJBMTI4S1ciLCJlbmMiOiJBMTI4Q0JDLUhTMjU2In0.0lMlSBb0mzYbuV6M0P9Qst0JijUl2YvuVxaBtAsVEfcUkKLRsO2p1w.PCY7zSD0H
HuUCZZSsEbnFg.Z5QUEHlGNDQDoL8UsIKnakAxalwcGU7CX5rUerKKbrem25tc8GyIcmxPasp4KzFF9caR20lH7_lc6M1QlYssBEYEcI4DM50P-t8Mtr-PhDA.-Vdgrpt4t96Lk_N1hPCMYg; SMUSRMSG=; Navajo=+eGoE8a0fQmcgzcWwCp5hHDE/d2qhD+3PWhAGpDtbjdcarcbVJ04ReK6NKYsEQp6Rnew1G
OvnH0-; SMSESSION=2a3mfLKCU39E56N+0e9O8WDQTAQ3RZ9FCxsd0khmmKUMmfg1NOzRVAE/KJLvqSTmoowZkHZlh4BMCchhlv+Ej2ePzTdo1fzWLAIrGZwiPOobjqJnOZ8Xb+RluEXcZxsHoGVSLpcT51x3uw5Xd9E39XdupiYRoqkEQHRpC4KgsJts6lsU1WIXGfnskAxLIwt+bXSMLQVoccQkjnR0bQRI1RME
apxW0DV+RZDLjbiZTqC7PmXhbLmFLfONZxD0B2TPeH9w8YtL8pBNardx35CQyZ/j3ICutB/Qt/kTirFAotJhYAKQNG2O9vdmoiny3quPX3d87AhM2bmsIOAUetw5imTkwaU3KEgY5upSlXKTqvpqjcgQubVGlXBwPOzJJcLvEQJ4i4IwU6neUv5SvjuzOGhs3buyMbr63P2s1/3pyUOnn955Qmte/joWWoxVq+85AkJ
hkgM3wrlj9DMwsLzbqwU1JCbU1lDwjkNZzQci5s3QMaJjq27PmudijeZQ5cT3ZlgBjCef40AlJuMOzo6BfnS98nGWxvPHO2KIwXYloYx6u9uDQGbm6PUVDSwQSk5Nk5aPs53fvUO47AhjudjCs/l+nxgOW1uxNL6iZSDyKwXYnzLkLCnK/qPPvUlnULbjIGNNKxgtcH+yIdwFM9pUfEfIhaTthR1wK7MLKzFsqRijy
EiQF4wBrTuSaFjt84O3RqnNai/3iMUrZ8ajS1AasWaiZI+tAHaJIAQMceyzdHEOh6jdI2z7Mah6Gbu+yKMMX3AlotYidfaNcGtbieazaDgGe7oCpncpw4+y3OnLQy3eEfu7swg/Ty7IXZV2c6gzcoXzxar7mcP1stdJfovfciz2+pCLuJnL3pcAP7atGgmoJdK7MtgbA3GNgw/sj7vcqUgNoyKyqoTbfRqqZwaAgsL
kSdwXH6UAfxqiF2xo34nxyrFdaMkzEYNZCiU+VTQRrpjx+Y+lACTIhRTeThdPfc1Gy0CUs3bEzQiznlffhoYKwq/RNv43ySxY4QUb3iYE07JgfpXj5FdzL5PuMr1Y48ZWXf84OE0UMJ5gi31Fp85c2ewDLjm3I7iQhVQO6BsC9vXpjERWFwmDmx1mZUkgLBLjl4u7sSYIJER2GphP8G3+bt4D+WC5lCzUShK/PNOSx
SCZcSy8oMS+6BNbDUO1qU6w5QERvi5hkklKiQXhLTR4JJzi22tcyyHIcxNTTwKX6MPHKi9cjvHpQjzyILhg4SPzaTrtCY+ZUuFtqfblpt3jYGPfehDFO3grLK0J8AzFm'  --compressed >  "$httpsconf->{localdir}/$target_file.html"`;
                } elsif ($filespec eq "file3") {
                my $curl_code = `curl "sample.com/wells/DisplayMDXResult.asp?ReportId=789"  -H 'Cookie: SMDEVICE=eyJhbGciOiJBMTI4S1ciLCJlbmMiOiJBMTI4Q0JDLUhTMjU2In0.i0N-N4zs25tS1YyxFsPgghtTvb-j1yoJlNcMwFJt0YlczWTtzJbLyQ.VaOp-3bOsKZsFZK3J-5Ttw._d967mUZH2Oly5YVAZvxwbeud4Y86gy3K5r8dDpupC3aLnhYd7ZTB1r-4wsuvVzDtUGATftexCVNPMItz0AxwjQ8zuHpfEbNXVlgCEYwWDw.thTbm9lUA_B7C62X4mIa6g; SMUSRMSG=; Navajo=HghuGrY7Sps24/1DNa6srjbey+aj+UXdfPIARKvhZrg3dVBKiKYosBr/onJVE2iz0DdUAuty48M-; SMSESSION=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'  --compressed > "$httpsconf->{localdir}/$target_file.html"`;
                }
```

Answer (score 5):

Should be able to read and write the same cookie, like

```
curl --cookie cookie_file --cookie-jar cookie_file https://...
```

or just

```
curl -b cookie_file -c cookie_file  https://...
```

In principle you'd use `-c` option to write a cookie file when/before logging in with your credentials and then use `-b` to read from it for the next request(s) but it should work in one as well.

See [cookies in curl docs](https://curl.se/docs/http-cookies.html), and the [Cookies chapter](https://everything.curl.dev/http/cookies) in *Everything curl* book.

---

Or, being in a Perl program we can use Perl's most extensive support for network programming.

One established set of tools for this rests around [LWP::UserAgent](https://metacpan.org/release/GAAS/libwww-perl-6.03/view/lib/LWP/UserAgent.pm), with a host of other classes.  See an overview in [LWP](https://metacpan.org/pod/LWP).  The other prominent one has [Mojo::UserAgent](https://metacpan.org/pod/Mojo::UserAgent), in the middle of a whole web framework. I'll use `LWP::UserAgent` for an example below.

By default the cookie support is turned off so we first need to enable it, either via [its attribute](https://metacpan.org/pod/LWP::UserAgent#cookie_jar) or using the [method](https://metacpan.org/release/GAAS/libwww-perl-6.03/view/lib/LWP/UserAgent.pm#$ua-%3Ecookie_jar).  Then the user-agent object will store all cookies (in an [HTTP::Cookies](https://metacpan.org/pod/HTTP::Cookies) object), managing and sending them as needed with each request.

```
use warnings;
use strict;
use feature 'say';

use LWP::UserAgent;

my $url = shift // die "Usage: $0 url\n";

my $ua = LWP::UserAgent->new;
$ua->cookie_jar({ file => "$ENV{HOME}/.cookies.txt" });
$ua->cookie_jar->save;

# How does the website expect a log in?

my $response = $ua->get( $url );

die $response->status_line if not $response->is_success;

say $ua->cookie_jar->as_string;
# ...
```

I can't include specific login code since it's not stated in the question how it need be done.  If the site uses HTTP basic auth then `credentials` is a good way to do it, but if it is cookies based then you want to request the form for that etc (and it can use both).

Or one can set up cookies via attributes in the constructor instead

```
my $ua = LWP::UserAgent->new(
    cookie_jar => {
        file => "$ENV{HOME}/.cookies.txt",
        autosave => 1,
    }
);
```

If there is no need to save cookies in a file to enable cookies we can do simply

```
my $ua = LWP::UserAgent->new( cookie_jar => {} );
```

and don't need lines with `->cookie_jar` (can still use it, like  `$ua->cookie_jar->as_string`). Now a "cookie_jar" is kept in memory and discarded as the program ends.

Either way, running the program with the input string `https://www14.sample.com` (what that `https://sample.com` from the question resolves to for me) prints

```
Set-Cookie3: vsid=917vr3900381853629235; path="/"; domain=www14.sample.com; path_spec; expires="2027-01-17 07:56:25Z"; HttpOnly; version=0
```

(printed only for a demo)

Another way about this is to use [WWW::Mechanize](https://metacpan.org/pod/WWW::Mechanize), in which cookies are taken care of, and more goodies provided.  On the other end, there are Perl bindings for [libcurl](https://curl.se/libcurl/), module [Net::Curl](https://metacpan.org/pod/Net::Curl)

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively, consider using the Perl modules [LWP::UserAgent](https://metacpan.org/pod/LWP::UserAgent) or [WWW::Mechanize](https://metacpan.org/pod/WWW::Mechanize).